# Need Web based reporting/Graphing Engine ForMySQL

Tags: mysql, reporting

I have inherited the project. The project is run in A language called Xojo.  The database backend is mysql.  Xojo essentially creates A compiled CGI that contains all of the UI and business logic.

I need to find a reporting tool that allows for semi technical people to query and create results to an HTML screen, allows drill down on the summary items, download an Excel version of the report and makes pretty graphs to keep the folks in dust and C-Suite happy.

As I am clueless in this area of applications, I would love to hear the ins and outs of the various reporting engines.  We are a mac based shop

Comment: Interesting tool, but the language is in fact a variant of Basic, with Xojo being the IDE, anyway, do you want a tool that integrates with Xojo?, or are you looking for something that it's not bound to it?

Comment: Miguel:  Yes its a slick tool for web development  (think vb6 before all the .Net crud got in the way)  .    I do not need the tool to be part of it.  As long as I can embed the results of the tool in an iframe I can use whatever tool I wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any tool that integrates with your IDE (Xojo) directly, but if you don't mind using something that's outside of it, then you can use pretty much any reporting/bi tool you want, i recommend you to evaluate several of them and pick the one that better fit your needs, according to what you ask in your question, you look for something like [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com/), this tool lets you create reports by pure drag and drop, and if you like doing some SQL yourself, you can edit the query to achieve better results, it also does drill downs, exports to Excel (among other formats), let you view reports in any browser (even mobile ones) and you can embed them like [this](http://www.dbxtra.com/help-file/web_report_widget.htm).

The only problem is that for running the web reports and designing them, you need a server with Windows, it could be any Windows in fact, and you can even run it inside a Virtual Machine, so if you're a Mac only environment, you can setup one computer to act as a server with a Windows 7 virtual machine running on VMware Fusion or Parallels (or even Virtual Box).